# How to make vuetify stable

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vue 2 and just started a project with vuetify. at the beginning I could make it work, but after some uses it stopped working and I get this error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl' in '/Users/marcelorocha/Documents/Proyecto Express/sistemavue/src/plugins'

> ERROR in ./src/plugins/vuetify.js 3:0-37
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl' in '/Users/marcelorocha/Documents/Proyecto Express/sistemavue/src/plugins'
> @ ./src/main.js 2:0-27

> webpack compiled with 1 error

> WAIT  Compiling...                                                                                                                23:06:41

> Compiling...

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                             >23:06:43

> error  in ./src/plugins/vuetify.js

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl' in '/Users/marcelorocha/Documents/Proyecto Express/sistemavue/src/plugins'

> ERROR in ./src/plugins/vuetify.js 3:0-37
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl' in '/Users/marcelorocha/Documents/Proyecto Express/sistemavue/src/plugins'
> @ ./src/main.js 2:0-27

> webpack compiled with 1 error

I tried to restar the computer as I made no changes to the package json or node modules, only some components and main.js

Comment: Did you install the vuetify version for Vue 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, try to clean npm dependencies, remove the folder node_modules, maybe you can remove the file package-lock.json or yarn.lock depending on which package manager are you using and install again, also you can try to clear cache of your package manager

In case you are using npm

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

If the error persist execute

```
npm cache clear --force
```

And repeat the previous process

Warning: Be careful with these commands in production environments

Comment: thanks! Cristóbal Díaz Álvarez, im sorry i just answered tjos

Answer (score 0):

Did you recently update from Vuetify 1 to 2? Pretty sure you are using style import from version 1, when Vuetify used stylus loader. Look for a line like

```
@import '~vuetify/src/stylus/main'
```

and remove it.

If you are not using vuetify-loader, add styles with

```
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
```

otherwise vuetify-loader should handle it.

The setup for v2 with webpack setup is documented [here](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#webpack-install)

Comment: thank you @Moritz Ringler i forgot about it for a while but still very thankfull for your answer